# How do I set a material in renderman to use a specific UV map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, shaders, renderman-render-engine

My model has 4 separate UV maps for the head, arms/hands, legs/feet, and body. But i can't find a UV map node equivalent in Renderman. [image: The Cycles node setup]

After converting the node setup to Renderman, it doesn't have a set UV map to use for that material and i can't find anything to match. [image]